# Progress bar with Tooltip message should be displayed always

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement where need to display the progress bar with tool tip message always .

Code to display the progress bar , but not sure how to display the tool tip message  always.

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">10%</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that stuff like this is much easier with a framework like bootstrap. Is that something you'd be willing to consider? See below.

```js
$('.tool_tip')
  .attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
  .attr('data-placement', 'right')
  .tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual'
  })
  .tooltip('show');
```

```css
.progress {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="progress" style="height: 30px;">
        <div class="progress-bar tool_tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Your Progress" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here's a second answer that is based on pure CSS, and not Bootstrap** -

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #ececec;
  color: #555;
  cursor: help;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper .tooltip {
  background: #1496bb;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
}

/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.wrapper .tooltip:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}  

/* CSS Triangles - see Trevor's post */
.wrapper .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid #1496bb 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}
  
.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* IE can just show/hide with no transition */
.lte8 .wrapper .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.lte8 .wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}

#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
    <div id="myProgress" class="wrapper">
      <div class="tooltip-toggle" aria-label="sample text" tabindex="0" id="myBar">10%</div>
       <div class="tooltip">Your Progress</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! We do not and we are not allowed to use bootstrap, It’s a old dev system ... we use dojo framework is it possible to apply using the dojo 1.7 framework..

Comment: I've added an additional answer that is based on pure CSS (no javascript or bootstrap). It's also based on your original html code. Hope this helps.